# Is it possible to verify intra-class behavior with OCMock

Tags: ios, ocmock

Given this simple class

```
@implementation ExampleClass

- (void)doStuff
{
  [self doOtherStuff];
}

- (void)doOtherStuff
{
  // something happens here
}

@end
```

is it possible to test behavior of that class that one of its own methods calls another? for instance, in the above example can I use OCMock to verify doOtherStuff is called? I've tried the following:

```
id mock = OCMClassMock([ExampleClass class]);
[mock doStuff];
OCMVerify([mock doOtherStuff]);
```

but it doesn't actually invoke the call to **doStuff** at all due to the fact that it's a class mock. Is this only possible with a partial mock - and if so, what would be an alternative design of the ExampleClass to not need a partial mock? Bear with me - newbie to unit testing and mocking here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what partial mocks are for. Create an instance of `ExampleClass`, then create a partial mock for that instance. Using that partial mock you can now verify and/or stub methods on that instance, e.g. verify that `doOtherStuff` is called.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Question though - how does that reconcile with the view out there that partial mocks are "the devil"? Is doing this kind of intra-class testing a bad practice in the unit test world? Also, love your OCMock library!

Comment: Well, the technique described above is basically a variation of the [test-specific subclass pattern](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test-Specific%20Subclass.html). It has its uses but many people consider a design in which the two methods end up in different classes superior. In that case you can substitute the other class with a normal mock, usually with dependency injection.